# ppt animation + rhide all animation after last animation sequence

Tags: animation, powerpoint

I have a slide with text, followed by 3 pics which are animation sequences. the flow is based on mouse click and something like this-
slide begins
click - text box
click - pic1
click - pic2
click - pic3
Now, i want to hide all 3 pics after the pic3 is displayed. I do not want to hide pic1 and pic2 before pic3 appears.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trigger function in animation Tab to find the suitable sequence. Use move earlier and later to change the sequence of the images.